# Critical points of multivariable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

Im trying to find the critical points a function, but when setting the partial derivatives equal to zero, i cant figure out how to solve them, for this particular function:

$\ f(x,y)= -(x^2-1)^2-(x^2y-x-1)^2 $

$\nabla f(x,y)=(-4x^3(y^2+1)+6x^2y+2x(2y-3)-2,-2x^4y+2x^3+2x^2) $

When plugging $\ -4x^3(y^2+1)+6x^2y+2x(2y-3)-2=0 $ into my calculator and trying to solve for $\ x $ i get $\ x(2x^2(y^2+1)-3xy-2y+3)=-1 $ as a result which i don't know what to with.

Comment: Solve these as a set of equations with $f_x = f_y = 0$. You should find two critical points as $~(x, y) = (-1, 0), (1, 2)$.

Comment: use a *robot*: [ http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%5B%7BD%5B-%28x%5E2+-+1%29%5E2+-+%28x%5E2+y+-+x+-+1%29%5E2%2C+x%5D+%3D%3D+0%2C++++D%5B-%28x%5E2+-+1%29%5E2+-+%28x%5E2+y+-+x+-+1%29%5E2%2C+y%5D+%3D%3D+0%7D%2C+%7Bx%2C+y%7D%5D ]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the second equation, we can divide out a $-2x^2$ and it reduces to:

$$x^2 y - x - 1 = 0 \implies y = \dfrac{x+1}{x^2}$$

Substitute this into the first and it reduces nicely to:

$$-4x(x^2-1) = 0 \implies x = 0, \pm ~ 1$$

We toss out $x = 0$, due to division by zero.

Now, solve for the two $y$ values.

$$(x,y)=~(−1,0),~(1,2)$$

Comment: Where did you get the equation $x^2 y - x - 1 = 0$? Arent you supposed to set each of the derivatives equal to zero?

Comment: As I wrote, from the second equation, we have , $-2x^4y+2x^3+2x^2 = 0 \implies x^2 y - x - 1 = 0$  (look at how you can divide out a $- ~ 2x^2$). Clear?

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*: Think of them like a system of equations. Don't forget $-2x^4y+2x^3+2x^2=0$, which you can divide by $2x^2$ on both sides, then solve for $y$ in terms of $x$ and plug it into the big mess you have.

Comment: As hideous as that looks at first, a big "chunk" of the $ \ f_x \ $ equation disappears after inserting the result for $ \ y \ $ , leaving something very simple to solve (with three solutions for $ \ x \ , $ one of which can be discarded immediately).